# save custom radio button state ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm using Ember and I'm required to use radio buttons on the page.  I've looked at many tutrials and posts about creating ember radio buttons and for the most part they work, I just can't seem to get past saving the state of the radio button.  When a user selects a button the view will change, either adding or subtracting a drop down at the moment.  The view changes no problem but the radio button doesn't save it's state, they all clear.  Clicking on the same radio button or an "inactive one" will let them work normally.

I used this site as my main reference http://thoughts.z-dev.org/2013/07/04/radio-buttons-in-ember-js/#comment-379

```
Ember.RadioButton = Ember.View.extend({
tagName: "input",
c: null,    //content
type: "radio",
value: null,
attributeBindings: ["name", "type", "value", "checked:unchecked:"],
click: function() {
    debugger;
    this._context.set('current', this.c);
    this.set("selection", this.$().val());
    //this.c.gid;
},
checked: function() {
    debugger;
    return this.get("value") == this.get("selection");
}.property('selection') 
});

//App.ShowMeRadio = Ember.ObjectController.extend({ 
App.ShowMeRadio = Ember.Object.extend({
    isSelected: ""
});

App.showMeRadio = App.ShowMeRadio.create();

{{#each content in view._context.groups.content}}
{{view Ember.RadioButton name=content.name selectionBinding="App.showMeRadio.isSelected" cBinding="content" value="name"}}{{content.name}}
{{/each}}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: `checked` is defined twice. First as a property having the value false, then as a computed property.

Comment: Woops forgot to take that out, checked, the property, was added maybe 10 minutes before I wrote this question, I've been trying different things since yesterday

Answer (score 0):

Your `RadioButton` view has the attribute `value="name"` and it should be a bare word: `value=name`.

Comment: weather I have qoutes around name or not ember takes it as a literal string, same with "content.name", is there any way I can use the properties in content?

Comment: Yes, sorry in that case it would be value=content.name

Comment: I tried that before I posted my question, it still takes it as a literal string.  The only way I've been able to read content correctly is by adding `defaultTemplate: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<label><input type="radio" {{ bindAttr disabled="view.disabled" name="content.name" option="content.gid" value="content.gid" checked="view.checked"}} />{{content.name}}</label>')`